# How can I programmatically add controls to a DataTemplate defined in XAML?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, addition

I have a simple DataTemplateSelector set up:

```
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is ParameterViewModel)
        {
            ParameterViewModel paramItem = item as ParameterViewModel;

            if (paramItem.ControlInfo.Type == "slider")
            {
                return element.FindResource("sliderParam") as DataTemplate;
            }
            else if (paramItem.ControlInfo.Type == "button")
            {
                return element.FindResource("buttonParam") as DataTemplate;
            }
                            ...... etc
```

This is all fine, I’ve added it to my XAML and it works as expected.

Now, what I want to do is: if a condition is met, add some extra controls to the DataTemplate before it is returned.
My first attempt was to create a StackPanel FrameworkElementFactory, and add the DataTemplate’s VisualTree  to it, along with the extra controls I wish to add, and then return a DataTemplate with the VisualTree set to the FrameWorkElementFactory.

E.g.

```
                FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));

                if (paramItem.ControlInfo.Type == "slider")
                {
                    spFactory.AppendChild((element.FindResource("sliderParam") as DataTemplate).VisualTree);
                }

  ...

                //add my extra controls 
                if(condition..)
                {
                    spFactory.AppendChild(extraControl);
                }

               return new DataTemplate { VisualTree = spFactory };
```

However, because the DataTemplate is defined in XAML, the VisualTree property will always return null.

How can I add a control to the DataTemplate?

Comment: why do you want to do that? I can only strongly discourage you to do that. It sounds useful but in reality i don't think you want that. Otherwise you can always use Usercontrols, or ContentControls to define "parts" of a template, that are again resolved with different templates or template selectors. Otherwise just create a datatemplate for all different representations, and/or use trigger to hide certain parts of it.

Comment: When I display a paramItem, if "the condition" is met I want to display the paramItem in a popup to force the user to enter a value for it. The only place I can see this possible to do is when the datatemplate is being selected. It seems logical to wrap a popup around the param if needs be. It doesn't seem right to create the exact same dataTemplate in XAML for every param just to wrap it in a popup.

Comment: @dowhilefor with this in mind do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: like i said, i create a datatemplate for these additional controls, and add them with a ContentControl, no special binding, just another ContentTemplate. Works pretty well.

Comment: @dowhilefor all i need to do is display the control in a popup if a condition is met, i feel there must be a better solution then replicating every control template and putting a <popup> around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
...
if (paramItem.ControlInfo.Type == "slider")
{
   spFactory.AppendChild(FactoryFromResource("sliderParam"));
}
...

private FrameworkElementFactory FactoryFromResource(string resource)
{
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = FindResource(resource) as DataTemplate;
    FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
    factory.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentTemplateProperty, dataTemplate);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Its worth pointing to the remark Section of the [FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx).

Comment: The OP asked how to add a datatemplate defined in xaml to a FrameworkElementFactory which I answered. Personally I load XAML from strings using XAMLReader.

Comment: I was not judging your answer, its perfectly valid, but it should be clear that this might not be supported in a future version, which on the other hand is pretty unlikely.